Trying to use Prisma for a simple use case, but I'm encountering an error: 'Invalid prisma.bookmark.findUnique() invocation.'
I'm working on a feature to add bookmarks based on userId and toolId. These two elements are passed from the frontend. I have debugged, and my API call is working fine until I add a link to PrismaDB.
In my API, I call this function and pass all the corresponding data to it:
export const updateBookmark = async (toolId: string, userId: string) => {
  if (!userId) {
    return "No user ID provided";
  }

  try {
    const existingBookmark = await prismaDB.bookmark.findUnique({
      where: {
        userId_toolId: { userId, toolId },
      },
    });

    if (existingBookmark) {
      await prismaDB.bookmark.delete({
        where: {
          id: existingBookmark.id,
        },
      });
      return "Bookmark deleted";
    } else {
      await prismaDB.bookmark.create({
        data: {
          userId: userId,
          toolId: toolId,
        },
      });
      return "Bookmark created";
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error updating bookmark:", error);
    throw new Error("Failed to update bookmark");
  }
};

However, I encounter this error:

prisma:info Starting a postgresql pool with 17 connections in PgBouncer mode.
prisma:error
Invalid prisma.bookmark.findUnique() invocation:
Server has closed the connection.
Error updating bookmark: PrismaClientInitializationError:
Invalid prisma.bookmark.findUnique() invocation:

Here is my schema:
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url = env("DATABASE_URL")
  directUrl = env("DIRECT_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model Bookmark {
  id String @id @default(cuid())
  userId String
  toolId String
  
  @@unique([userId, toolId], name: "userId_toolId")
}

And here is my prismadb:
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

declare global {
  var prisma: PrismaClient | undefined;
}

const prismadb =
  globalThis.prisma ||
  new PrismaClient({
    log: ["query", "info", "warn", "error"], // Detailed logging
  });

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") globalThis.prisma = prismadb;

export default prismadb;

How can I resolve this issue?
